# Sinatra sessions - why is what I put in different from what I get out?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, session-state

I've got the following declared:

```
set :sessions, true
```

and then in my controller, I have:

```
session[$session_id] = user.session_id if save_successful
```

which sets the session, and then on a trip back to the server, I have:

```
session_id = session[$session_id]
```

But when I compare what I initially store in the session, I have:

```
a878bbd83f217daabec1b160b00bdde6 (initally)
d1e6264b87ae240be5a25a7edbcc97e5688df133cada1c7ab50661ae2f752b48 (on trip back)
```

Why is what I put into a session different from what I get out? and how do I make it the same???

Cheers,

Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted a bug report on https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/197#issuecomment-1648851

If I use just :id instead of :session_id then it works :~)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant for `$session_id` to be `:session_id` or `'session_id'`, variables that begin with dollar signs are global in Ruby (it is not the name of a key, but instead a globally visible reference to some object).

A good way to take a look would be to print `session.inspect` is the key what you think it should be?

Comment: Thanks for the help - yeah I was using $session_id = "session_id", but a symbol is a smarter way :)

I tried out session.inspect, and got 
Session inspect info is {"session_id"=>"324c31e22b6bcfa318efeb60d0308955"}
 when I initially put the information into the session, then on the round trip back I get:
"============> Session inspect info is {"session_id"=>"d1e6264b87ae240be5a25a7edbcc97e5688df133cada1c7ab50661ae2f752b48"}
"
So still the same problem - arrrghhh!